# Prestashop cart not updating with ajax but updates after a refresh

Tags: ajax, prestashop, e-commerce, cart

So I'm using Prestashop 1.7.7.4 for a client's project and It's my first e-commerce site. I was planning on using WooCommerce but the client asked for Prestashop specifically so here we are.

Here's my issue: I order something on the store, the product is added to the cart, but the cart visually doesn't show that. It used to, but at some point it stopped automatically updating the cart's information unless I refresh the page.

I looked around some forums and they mentioned checking the debugger and hook positioning but I think I got those two checked because the debugger is only showing warnings regarding some missing translations, and the Cart module is positioned on the displayTop hook which is what it was by default.

The only thing I remember doing that might be related is that, while testing, I did move some modules around but then I put them back in place. So at least in the case of the displayTop hook, everything is as it was. Can't guarantee the same for other hooks, but would it matter?

Since I'm not really very savvy with programming yet, nor Prestashop, I can't figure out where I should be looking for clues.

Any ideas about what I can do to get to the bottom of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to solve this issue is:

First, go to your PrestaShop directory, navigate to the 'themes' directory and edit 'core.js' file.

Second, find this code:

```
o.default.cart=e.resp.cart
```

and replace it with

```
o.default.cart=e.reason.cart
```

and save it.

Third, go to your PrestaShop BO and navigate to Modules menu, search for ps_shoppingcard module and reset it.

4th, go to the Advance parameters - Performance menu and click on Clear cache blue button.

That's it, now your ajax add to/remove from cart function works well.

P.S: resetting the Shopping Cart module may change it's position inside the hook it used to be showing in, you may need to change its position from Design - Positions menu.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by using the reset button for the cart module on the Modules page. Then you have to make sure the module is on the hook you want and it should be working.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I +1'd this answer since it solved my issue. If your issue didn't solve with this solution, you need to replace the core.js file from PS 1.7.7.x from themes folder with your current core.js file. Also don't forget to clear PS cache as well.